# Material is not a valid member of Workspace "Workspace" (Lua)

Tags: debugging, lua

```
print(newBrick.Material and newBrick.Name and newBrick.Color and newBrick.Size)
```

I want to print some properties of the new Instance, I made. But I get the error: "Material is not a valid member of Workspace "Workspace". I am very knew to programming and have no clue, what I made wrong. Here you can see the whole code it's about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZCY1.png

Comment: please don't post screenshots of post. Now I cannot simply copy paste problematic lines into my answer. share text as text. not as an image. that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a syntax error. Your syntax is correct. You're indexing a table field that does not exist.

In line 15:

```
print(newBrick.Material and newBrick.Name and newBrick.Color and newBrick.Size)
```

you index `newBrick.Material` but according to the error message `Material` is not a valid member of Workspace.

`newBrick` is the return value of `CreatePart`. While you create it as a new `Instance` in

```
local part = Instance.new("Part")
```

you assign `part = game.workspace` right befor you return `part`.

So instead of the `Instance` you index `game.workspace` with `Material`.

You probably wanted to add `game.workspace` as the parent of `part`.
Otherwise I cannot make sense of your code.

So either use

```
local part = Instance.new("Part", game.workspace)
```

or

```
local part = Instance.new("Part")
part.Parent = game.workspace
```

Also what do you want to achieve with line 15? If you want to print several values use a comma, not `and`. `and` is for boolean logic.

Comment: thank you so much for your perfect answer. I am so happy. And from now on I won't make the mistake with posting a screenshot. Thank you very much